# Can reading affect writing during thread race?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am asking this question to understand better the phenomenon of thread races in C++ (but maybe this should be language independent...?).

Say that I have two threads, with a shared resource (say `int n`, with initial value 0).

Thread A works for a while until a value for `n` is found, so that at some point `n = /* some value here */;`.

Thread B busy waits for a value for `n`, something like `while(!n);`

`n` will be set only once by thread A and will not change. Now, there is going to be a race between thread A and B when `n` is set. However, in this case one thread is write-only and one thread is read-only, so I am wondering if there is actually a chance that the value of `n` is never set by thread A because of the race, thus making thread B hang forever.

So to sum up with an example:

```
int n = 0;

void threadA()
{
   cin>>n;
}

void threadB()
{
   while(!n);
   cout<<n<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    // Run threadA and threadB as parallel threads. (Or run threadA as a thread and call threadB from the main thread).
}
```

What happens when I enter some value for `n`?

Comment: Based on your explanation, there is no race condition.  Thread A will always assign a value, and Thread B will never proceed until a value is assigned.  If we could see the code, it might help understand the issue better.

Comment: @VincentUgenti Based on C++ standard this is a race condition.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I am definitely not a C++ expert but I can't see how Thread B gets past "while (!n)" until after a value is assigned to n.  Unless maybe it is a 64-bit integer on a 32-bit architecture.

Comment: Probably better to use an `std::atomic<int> n;`. Also busy waiting isn't such a good idea.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin added a brief example!

Comment: If the data type is atomic, there is no danger whatsoever. Otherwise the reader thread may momentarily see a value other than the one written by the writer thread.

Comment: @n.m. that would be perfectly fine! My point is: is there a chance that the writing thread doesn't successfully write n because the reading thread is busy reading it? My problem isn't if the reading thread stays blocked for a couple of iterations longer, but if the reading thread stays blocked *forever* since the writing thread fails to write on n. Can this happen?

Comment: What you really want here is called a "condition variable"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thread B can get stuck waiting forever. The reason is simpe—in C++, you need an explicit synchronisation "handshake" (either an atomic operation or a synchronisation primitive such a mutex) to make sure that values written by one thread are visible to another. You have no such synchronisation opertaion in your code, so it's not guaranteed that thread B will proceed.

It's perfectly possible that thread B will read 0 into a cache and the cacheline will never get updated, simply because there is no reason to do so—no atomic or synchronisation operation which could force the update. As far as the compiler is concerned, thread B reading `n` leads to undefined behaviour, so it can safely assume that B does not read `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code in the question it is possible that the thread will block forever.

The compiler/cpu may look at the code `cin >> n` and decide to optimize away the assignment to `n`, (even though it's prompted for input) as it has detected that `n` won't be subsequently used. Even if it's not optimized away it may well sit in a cpu cache line that is never flushed to main memory, causing the other thread to never see the value.

To avoid this you should use either an atomic type (from C++11 onwards) or use an appropriate memory barrier for platform.